# My Maps project stops with "Method 'Android.Gms.Maps.MapView.get_Map' not found."

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run a simple map page on Xamarin Forms but I'm getting this error:

System.MissingMethodException
Method 'Android.Gms.Maps.MapView.get_Map' not found.

I saw this topic in https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88135/xamarin-forms-map-error-on-andriod-after-updating-xamarin-forms-and-maps-to-2-3-3-193 but got no help.

My environment is Xamarin Studio Community on a Macbook and the Xamarin.Forms.Maps package version is 2.3.3.193.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The latest nuget for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps (v42.1001.0 as of right now) does not work with the latest version of Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.3.193. Try backing off to a slightly older release.

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps v29.0.0.2 seems to work just fine with it.

This happens from time to time when you update packages to the latest releases, and usually simply backing off a version or two of dependent packages like this will fix it.